# Neumann boundary condition on the radial Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

For central-potential problems in textbook quantum mechanics, the boundary condition is physically motivated. For finite-range potentials, we match to free-particle solutions (tunneling or scattering). For hard-wall potentials, we require a node at the wall position. In more sophisticated models, like the Hartree-Fock atom or the muffin-tin model, the boundary conditions are similarly motivated by the potential.

I recently encountered a model which enforces a Neumann condition on the wave function. That is, it solves
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2mr^2} \frac{d}{dr}\left[ r^2 \frac{d R_l}{dr} \right] + \left[\frac{\hbar^2l(l+1)}{2mr^2} + V(r) - E\right]R_l(r), \qquad R_l(0) = \left.\frac{dR_l}{dr}\right|_a=0,
$$
where $a > 0$ is some pre-defined distance from the origin. I am struggling to understand what this boundary condition implies physically.

Often, Neumann conditions arise from some kind of "no-flux" condition. The nearest parallel I can think of is the radial probability current
$$
\hat r\cdot\vec j = \frac{\hbar}{m} \Im[\psi^*\hat r\cdot\nabla\psi] 
= \frac{\hbar}{m}  \sum_{lm}\sum_{l'm'} R_l\frac{dR_{l'}}{dr} \Im[Y_{lm}^*(\theta,\phi)Y_{l'm'}(\theta,\phi)]
$$
The Neumann condition above would force this to be zero over on the surface of the sphere of radius $a$. But I'm having a hard time drawing a physical interpretation of this. The best I can think of is a semi-classical picture, where electrons near $r=a$ "reflect" back toward the origin.  Is this interpretation sensible, and is there any precedent for this being a useful condition to impose, in the context of atomic or solid-state physics?